# Only changing value when inheriting

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a very simple Pokémon application in C#. I was uncertain on how to set up the relationship between the Pokémon and their fighting type but I just ended up doing the following:

```
 abstract class Pokemon
{
    private int number;
    private string name;
    protected string weakness;
    protected string strength;

    public Pokemon(int number, string name)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        weakness = "none";
        strength = "none";
    }
}
```

I then made seperate classes that inherit Pokemon only to change the specific weakness and strength of the type.

```
class Fire : Pokemon
{
    public Fire(int number, string name) : base(number, name)
    {
        weakness = "Water";
        strength = "Grass";
    }
}
```

Is it bad etiquette to create subclasses with the sole purpose of simply changing some of the initial values of the parent?

From here on, I just intend on doing the following when "creating" Pokémon for the application

```
        pokemon = new Pokemon[6];
        pokemon[0] = new Grass(001, "Bulbasaur");
        pokemon[1] = new Grass(002, "Ivysaur");
        pokemon[2] = new Grass(003, "Venusaur");
        pokemon[3] = new Fire(004, "Charmander");
        pokemon[4] = new Fire(005, "Charmeleon");
        pokemon[5] = new Fire(006, "Charizard");
```

Any and all advice on how to improve the application or how to use inheritance properly is much appreciated :)

Comment: Another possible solution would be to use an enum in the constructor, so you would pass something in like `PokemonType.Grass` or `PokemonType.Fire`.  You could even set it up to accept a `List<PokemonType>` for pokemon with two types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inheritance looks OK but you may do some improvements. First, you don't need to define protected fields for weakness and strength, use protected properties instead. Second, using string type for weakness/strength doesn't seem to be the best choice. I would go with an Enum type.

```
enum PokemonComponent {
   Water,
   Grass
}

abstract class Pokemon
{
    private int number;
    private string name;
    protected Pokemon(int number, string name)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    }
    protected abstract PokemonComponent Weakness {
      get;
    }
    protected abstract PokemonComponent Strength {
       get;
    }
}

class Fire : Pokemon
{    
    public Fire(int number, string name) : base(number, name)
    {
    }
    protected override PokemonComponent Weakness {
      get {
         return PokemonComponent.Water;
      }
    }
    protected override PokemonComponent Strength {
      get {
         return PokemonComponent.Grass;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make the `Weakness` and `Strength` public.

Comment: @lokusking It is not known if OP wants to expose these properties. He likely wants but since we just see protected fields in his code, I kept the properties protected as well.

Comment: @Shelby yes it is not recommended to make public fields. But if you want to expose those values, you can make those properties public instead of protected.

Comment: Properties should be public if they need to be accessed by other classes. If you want other classes (say, an ASP.NET display page, or a battle simulator) to access your Pokemon's strengths and weaknesses, you should make them public.

Comment: You can also make properties that can be publicly read, but only private or protected when it comes to writing:

`public PokemonComponent Strength { get; protected set; }`

This way your property does not need to be abstract; you can set it in the subclass constructors as you did before.